# How can I rewrite this countdown timer using RxPY?

Tags: rxjs, rx-py

Here's RxJS code I'm trying to reproduce with RxPY.

```js
const counter$ = interval(1000);
counter$
  .pipe(
    mapTo(-1),
    scan((accumulator, current) => {
      return accumulator + current;
    }, 10),
    takeWhile(value => value >= 0)
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

```
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
0
-1
```

And here's what I through was equivalent but is not

```py
counter = rx.interval(1)
composed = counter.pipe(
    ops.map(lambda value: value - 1),
    ops.scan(lambda acc, curr: acc + curr, 10),
    ops.take_while(lambda value: value >= 0),
)
composed.subscribe(lambda value: print(value))
```

```
9
9
10
12
15
19
```

Could someone help me to understand what I'm missing here?

Comment: MapTo doesn't subtract from anything. It just turns every value into -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know python at all, but I do notice one difference in your `map` between your js and python:

```js
mapTo(-1) // always emits -1
```

-- vs --

```py
ops.map(lambda value: value - 1)  # emits interval index - 1
```

I think the solution is simple, just remove the "value":

```py
ops.map(lambda value: -1)
```

However, if your "current value" is always `-1` you can simplify by not using `map` at all and put `-1` in your `scan()` function.  Here's what it looks like in rxjs:

```js
const countDown$ = interval(1000).pipe(
  scan(accumulator => accumulator - 1, 10)
  takeWhile(value => value >= 0)
);
```

Comment: That's very clear, thank you very much BizzyBob!